# Scaling height of bars to container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I'm wanting to scale the bar heights to the size of the SVG. http://jsfiddle.net/6d7984oa/

```
function d3_bar(s, dataset, barPadding) {

    var self = s[0],
        w = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("width")),
        h = parseInt(d3.select(self).style("height")),

        svg = d3.select(self)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - d;
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d) {

            return d;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
        });

}
```

I've tried quite a few things but the math never works.

```
    .attr("height", function(d) {

        var min = 1,
            max = h,
            diff = max - min;

        return h - ( diff ? ((d - min) / diff) * h : 1 );
    })
```

Struggling to see how this may be done.

Comment: Do you mean: you want the data (which will represent the height of the bars) to be **in relation to the height of the svg**, so that your data will always fit in the svg? I am asking just to be sure :-)

Comment: Correct. I'd like the bar heights to scale in size according to the SVG height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use D3 scales. A lot of info can be found here: [Quantitative scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales).

A basic linear scale goes like this:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                     .domain([0, d3.max(yourdata)])
                     .range([0,h]);
```

Please look up the d3.max() function. Basically it looks for the largest value in the given array, but you can use a function to specify what value to look at, in case your data is an array of objects.

The linear scale can be explained as following: 
The domain stands for the values that go in, the values that need to be scaled into something else. You give a range of values, the min and the max values between '[]'. In your case, this is the data representing the height.

The range of a scale is what comes out. So you define the min and the maximum possible outcomes, in our case 0 and the width of the svg.

So what happens when you use the scale? well, say your data goes from 0 to 100 and the width of your svg is 50 units. When your data is 0, the scale will return 0, when your data is 100, your scale will return 50. So if your data would be 50, then the scale will return.... 25. I choose easy numbers here, it works well on more difficult cases too :-).

**EDIT**: if forgot to mention how to use the scale for lets say your height attribute:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - d;
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d);})
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
        });
```

presuming of course that you named the scale 'yScale'.

**Edit 2**: My scale code had an error in the range. When scaling the y axes, you need to set the height in the range, not the width. So i fixed that.

Further more, when setting the y attribute of your rect, you need to use the scale for that one as well. Otherwise the bar height is scaled, but the matching y position isn't, resulting in awkward positioning of your rect tags. I should have mentioned that. Here is the correct code:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - yScale(d);
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d);})
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
        });
```

You can see that I have changed the y attribute function using the yScale as well.

I apologize for the faulty code, I should check it better in the future.